# I am using button in Lightning table and i wish to remove the button border. I try to give css class in typeAtributes but it doesn't work

Tags: datatable, salesforce-lightning, lwc, lightning

{ label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type:'button',initialWidth:200,typeAttributes: { label: {fieldName: 'Name'},class:"borderRemove" },sortable: true}
//css class
.borderRemove{ border:none; }

Answer (score 0):

just add *variant: 'base'* to typeAttributes
so in your case it should look like this:

```
typeAttributes: { label: {fieldName: 'Name'}, variant: 'base'}
```

class:"borderRemove" - should be removed